# Scilab: apply function to each element of vector (equivalent to Matlab's arrayfun() )

Tags: scilab

How to apply a function to each element of a vector in Scilab? I'm looking for something similar to Matlab's [arrayfun()](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) function. An extract of the Matlab documentation on `arrayfun()`:

> ```
>    B = arrayfun(func,A)
> ```
>
> `B = arrayfun(func,A)` applies the function func to the elements of A, one element at a time. arrayfun then concatenates the outputs from func into the output array B, so that for the ith element of A, `B(i) = func(A(i))`.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the other answer, some of times you can simply input an array in a function. But depending on the operations your function perform you may get wrong results. If you want to avoid that, you can simply define your own `arrayfun`, like this:

```
function B = matrixfun(func,A)
    for i = 1 : size(A,'r')
        for j = 1 : size(A,'c')
            B(i,j) = func(A(i,j))
        end
    end
endfunction
```

I called it `matrixfun` because it is more general. As an example, think of a `toHex` function that converts an real number `x` to a string representing it as hexadecimal.

```
function s = toHex(n)
    s = "";
    n = round(n)
    if n == 0 then
        s = "0";
    else
        while n >= 1
            select modulo(n,16)
                case 15 then s = "F" + s
                case 14 then s = "E" + s
                case 13 then s = "D" + s
                case 12 then s = "C" + s
                case 11 then s = "B" + s
                case 10 then s = "A" + s
                else s = string(modulo(n,16)) + s;
            end
            n = floor(n / 16)
        end
    end
endfunction

A = grand(4,4,"uin",0,50); //random matrix
B = toHex(A);
C = matrixfun(toHex,A);
```

You can check the results in the console:

```
--> disp(A) //original random matrix

   37.   14.   4.    42.
   17.   2.    18.   48.
   23.   37.   31.   21.
   16.   39.   43.   17.

--> disp(B) //wrong results

!5  14  4   10  !
!               !
!1  2   2   0   !
!               !
!7  5   15  5   !
!               !
!0  7   11  1   !

--> disp(C) //right results

!25  E   4   2A  !
!                !
!11  2   12  30  !
!                !
!17  25  1F  15  !
!                !
!10  27  2B  11  !
```